# Google Apps won't allow "Active Content" in HTML, and UiApp class has been depreciated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Have been trying to follow the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) to creating a pie chart and from there develop some  dashboard features in Google Apps Script. I found out that when you implement the calling of a script function (in the example it would be the drawChart() function), that is considered "Active Content" as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#sandbox_mode). 
I have seen other examples that don't use HTML, but those all seem to require the use of the UiApp class, which has been depreciated. So, is the only way to get a dashboard/graphing feature in Google Apps Script to have an HTTPS security certificate? It seems rather limiting if this is the case. I see a post or two mentioning a similar frustration getting only a white screen, and I believe that is due to the HTTPS limitation.

Originally I didn't post code because I felt the issue here was pretty clear. Here is the code I have. I also tried a simple HTML "Hello World" file that didn't have any functions/scripts, and that worked. Here is the script as it relates to my Google Sheet:

```
 function OpenChart(){
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('DummyChart');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Statistics");
    }
```

Here is the HTML file it calls:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Load charts package and visualization API
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});

      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(MakeChart);

      //Here is the script I think could be causing a problem
      function MakeChart() 
      {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var s = ss.getSheets();
      var s = sheets[1];
      var UI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = UI.prompt("Please enter the first cell in the category").getResponseText();
      var ir = s.getRange(response);
      var n= 0;
      var stored = [];
      stored.push(["Income Category", "Frequency"]);
      while (ir.getValue()!= "") {
       n = n +1;
       ir = ir.offset(1, 0);
       }
       //Above we just set n, below we use n to fill our array
       ir = ir.offset(-n,0)

       for(i =0; i<n;i++) {
        stored.push([ir.getValue(),ir.offset(n+2,0).getValue()]);
        ir = ir.offset(1, 0);
       }
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       stored[]]);
       /*I tried to also load data here directly as is seen on the pie chart    example I used. This didn't have any affect*/


       var options = { 'chartArea:backgroundColor': "Azure",
       'is3D': true,
       'title': 'Test Chart'};

        //Now instantiate it

        var chart = new     google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

      }

     </script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="chartDiv" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The guide you linked to the piechart demo works just fine in apps script. If you post code people can show you where your issue may lay.  see: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzlyXzJOGq-bpsuS9teSsgdZ3DBM_XjOUClryBEAzPQ3_EySqo/exec

Comment: Thank you, I posted the code. I am not getting any syntax errors, I am just getting a white screen, and my suspicion was the security protocol Google implements. I am curious about what the difference is between what you did and what I did, as I saw your script work. Perhaps I am trying to get the code to pop up as a dialog box in Google Sheets?

Comment: Oh you are trying to run server side code on the client side. That will break things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of how this can work. I stuck with the basic example and added the values from the pie chart example to the spreadsheet. The client side will need to call the server side to get the data. The is done with `google.script.run`. You would modify getData() to suite your needs.

code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("charts").addItem("piechart", "openPieChart").addToUi()
}


function openPieChart(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("piechart");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "piechart")
}

function getData(){      
 return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
}
```

piechart.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getData()});

      function drawChart(values) {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(values);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Spencer! Just to be clear, what I need to do then is grab all the data within the .gs file, and not the .html file and just call that function from the .gs file the way you did; correct? The only other question I have is   what exactly the .withSuccessHandler's functionality is in the code you posted. Thanks much for the help, this would have been hard to find.

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure that this could work without a HTTPS secured website? I tried what you suggested here, and even specifically pasted in the code you suggested. I DO see the title, but after searching and searching, I can't seem to get the pie chart to pull up. Do you think it is because of that restriction that I need an HTTPS page? One last note, when I tried this with my file, I noticed the screen pulled up before the function in my .gs code finished. I thought the .withsuccessHandler() was supposed to make the HTML wait until a script was done.